# Unable to fix an error in a decompiled java file, possible fix?

Tags: java

Extracted the classes from a `.jar` library, and decompiled the classes to `.java` files. Now when I try to re-compile a java file, I am getting an error, which I am unable to resolve, here is the code:

```
    private void d(int paramInt)
{
    int i1 = paramInt;
    if (this.v)
    {
        i1 = paramInt;paramInt = this;
        if (this.r == 4) {
            paramInt.r = 0;
        }
        paramInt.q[paramInt.r] = i1;paramInt.r += 1;paramInt.s.clear();i1 = 0;
        break label78;
        paramInt.s.add(Integer.valueOf(paramInt.q[i1]));i1++;
        label78:
        for (i1 < paramInt.q.length; paramInt.s.size() > 2; paramInt.s.addAll(paramInt.t))
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ where the error occurs
        {
            paramInt.t.clear();
            for (i1 = 0; i1 + 2 < paramInt.s.size(); i1++)
            {
                int i5 = ((Integer)paramInt.s.get(i1 + 2)).intValue();int i4 = ((Integer)paramInt.s.get(i1 + 1)).intValue();int i3 = ((Integer)paramInt.s.get(i1)).intValue();int i2 = paramInt;int i6 = a(i3, i4);paramInt.t.add(Integer.valueOf(i2 = a(i2 = b(i2 = b(i3, i4), i5), i6)));
            }
            paramInt.s.clear();
        }
        i1 = ((Integer)paramInt.s.get(0)).intValue();
    }
    if (this.u != i1)
    {
        if (this.o != null)
        {
            this.o.onImageRecognitionResult(i1);
        }
        this.u = i1;
    }
}
```

This is what I obtain when I compile the file via command line:

```
    C:\Users\oblivion\Desktop\EADMatching.jar.src\com\arlab\imagerecognition>javac A
Rmatcher.java
ARmatcher.java:385: error: > expected
      for (i1 < paramInt.q.length; paramInt.s.size() > 2; paramInt.s.addAll(para
mInt.t))
                                 ^
ARmatcher.java:385: error: not a statement
      for (i1 < paramInt.q.length; paramInt.s.size() > 2; paramInt.s.addAll(para
mInt.t))
              ^
2 errors
```

How to fix?

Comment: The answer is there in the error `ARmatcher.java:385: error: not a statement`. The first part of the for loop should be a statement, setting the value of i1.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i1 < paramInt.q.length; paramInt.s.size() > 2; paramInt.s.addAll(paramInt.t))
```

That is the for loop that is causing issues, compare it to the for loop a few lines below:

```
for (i1 = 0; i1 + 2 < paramInt.s.size(); i1++)
```

You can see that the first loop has completely incorrect syntax. The java documentation explains the correct for loop syntax:

[Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)